# How to Resolve Function Template Generics for Signal/Slot System?

Tags: kotlin, callback, signals-slots

I'm trying to develop a simplistic signals/slots system in Kotlin. Here's what I have so far:

```
open class Signal<T : Function<Unit>>() {
    val callbacks = mutableListOf<T>()

    open fun addCallback(slot: T) {
        callbacks.add(slot)
    }

    open fun emit(vararg params: Any) {
        for(call in callbacks) {
            call(*params)
        }
    }
}

fun test(myarg: Int) = println(myarg)

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val myevent = Signal<(Int) -> Unit>()
    myevent.addCallback(::test)
    myevent.emit(2)
}
```

The idea is one would create an instance of `Signal` along with a generic template to dictate which parameters are used for the callbacks. Callbacks can then be added to the `Signal`. Finally, whenever the `Signal` needs to be... well... "signaled", the `emit` method is used. This method passes all the parameters to the corresponding callbacks if necessary.

The issue is this code results in the following error:

`kotlin\Signal.kt:30:4: error: expression 'call' of type 'T' cannot be invoked as a function. The function 'invoke()' is not found`

The line in question is:
`call(*params)`

Any recommendations on how to handle things from here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because [`Function`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-function.html) is an empty interface ([source](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/44ecfb2fb8630560aac78422e9f053c1cdfbc158/core/builtins/src/kotlin/Function.kt#L24)).

The various function types that actually have `invoke` operators are all defined one by one [here](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/69ee88871f611f7f949c363533aae50e1af9f06f/libraries/stdlib/jvm/runtime/kotlin/jvm/functions/Functions.kt), as `Function0`, `Function1`, etc.

I don't think you'll be able to create a `Signal` implementation that may have callbacks with any number and any type of parameters. Could you perhaps get by with only having callbacks with a single parameter?

```
open class Signal<T> {
    val callbacks = mutableListOf<(T) -> Unit>()

    open fun addCallback(slot: (T) -> Unit) {
        callbacks.add(slot)
    }

    open fun emit(param: T) {
        for (call in callbacks) {
            call(param)
        }
    }
}

fun test(myarg: Int) = println(myarg)

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val myevent = Signal<Int>()
    myevent.addCallback(::test)
    myevent.emit(2)
}
```

(Note that you could replace both usages of `(T) -> Unit` here with `Function1<T, Unit>`.)

Comment: Ahhh, thanks for the clarification. Quick question then, could something closer to the hypothetical implementation be possible with KFunction? I noticed it has a “call” function that takes an indefinite number of params?

Comment: That would let you pass in an arbitrary number of parameters, but you'd essentially lose their types in the process, which is quite a trade-off.